# Algorithm for optimal resource arrangement

Tags: algorithm, matching

Here's the description of the problem

1. Given some rooms which will be available for a period of time(say one week) with capacity(Say 6 people for room type A, 10 people for room type B)
2. Given a series of people wants to sleep in one of these rooms during this time range for several nights(e.g Alice wants to take a spot at Monday and Wednesday nights, Bob wants to take a spot at Tuesday and Wednesday nights).
3. There exists some restrictions between these people(e.g. Alice doesn't want to stay with Bob in one room).

How do you determine if these rooms can hold so many peoples?

If Yes. Display the arrangement

If Not. Show the max value of people these rooms can hold, and display the arrangement

Will there be a generic algorithm to deal with this kind of resource arranging problem?

What if there are more restrictions?

For instance. People would prefer to stay in one room if they want to take a static spot if they don't have a gap during their staying(e.g. Bod stays at Tuesday and Wednesday, So he wants to stay in same spot for the two nights.)

Comment: You need to post the code you’ve tried and why it isn’t working. Sample input data with expected output and what your actual output is would be ideal. In the worst case, at least some pseudo code if this is a straight algorithmic issue

Comment: Possibly related to Knapsack problem

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the maximum [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) problem to this problem in polynomial time, proving that your problem is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). Thus, it is almost hopeless to look for an exact polynomial time algorithm (unless you want to give a go at proving that P=NP).

Consider the following reduction :

Let `G = (V,E)` denote a graph with `|V| = n` and `|E| = m` and let `k <= n` be an integer. We want to answer the following question : Does `G` contain an independent vertex set of size at least `k`?

Now we are going to construct an instance of your problem in the following way:

- Let the period of time be just a single night.
- Let there be a person (wanting to stay that one night) for every vertex in |V|, and say that two people do not want to stay in the same room if and only if there is an edge between the corresponding vertices in G.
- Let the set of rooms be constituted of a room of capacity k and n-k rooms of capacity 1.

This can obviously be done in polynomial time for any reasonable representation of your instances.

Now, if there is an independent set of size k or more in G, then you can fit k of the corresponding people in the big room (they won't mind being with each other) and fit the n-k other people in the single rooms.

Reciprocally, if you somehow manage to fit everyone in a room in a way that works then you will have exhibited an independent set of size k, corresponding to the k people in the big room (you know that there are k people in there because every room has to be full).

Thus, there is an independent set of size `k` in `G` if and only if the corresponding room assignment problem is solvable.

This proves the reduction and thus shows that your problem is NP-Hard.